# How to make an Individual Processing queue in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, queue, python-telegram-bot

I developed a telegram bot using python to download songs. My program takes input as a link from a user and stores in a queue. i have a function that processes the queue if there are items in it else wait for the queue to be filled. My functions are

```
global my_queue
my_queue =[]

def process_queue():
if my_queue !=None:
    #download the songs from the queue and send it to the user
else:
   #wait for the queue to be filled

@run_async
def get_input():
    #get input from the user and append the queue list with the item
```

How do i make my function process_queue() work individually and wait if the queue is empty? I need to make sure there is no overriding of files or race condition or deadlock.

Comment: A real `queue.Queue`, a separate thread and a `.get()`.

Comment: isint there an effient way? without thread

Comment: Please explain the relation threads → not efficient!